# Brand new Ubuntu LAMP install and the root user is denied from doing anything

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I just installed ubuntu server 12.04 with the LAMP stack and Openssh.  This is my first linux system so I'm pretty new to everything.  After the install the root user can't create a directory in the web root.  Also can't reset folder permissions or see a list of users.

I've google my heart out and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm not sure what info you need out of the system but I'd be happy to run any commands you dictate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As default Ubuntu has no password set for the root user (account name: root) set root password using the command in terminal

```
sudo passwd root
```

go to web directory and use this command to create a directory

```
sudo mkdir dir1
```

-dir1 is the directory name it will be created in `home` directory

Comment: That did it.  Don't know how i couldn't figure that out on my own.  Thank you!